# JavaScript: Element positioning

Tags: javascript, positioning

How can we change a position of an element in JS from a function?
object.style.left = "distance";
--> **It won't work with returned value, but with right format (12%, 12px).**

Code Example:

````
/*Get random value*/
function move() {
    var distance = 10*Math.random();
    return distance;
}
/*Assign to the style.left property of an element*/
function assign() {
    var distance = move();
    object.style.left = "distance";
}```
````

Comment: Please, check the line that starts with `object.style.left`. There string `"distance" is assigned to `object.style.left`, and not value of `distance` variable. Also having this example in Codepen(https://codepen.io/) can be helpful for others to understand how to help with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"distance" should not be a string. It's a variable. Try:

```
object.style.left = distance;
```